# Multithreading synchronization issues

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have code like this:

```
public class OtherClass {

    // OtherClass
    public synchronized static void firstMethod() {
        System.out.println("FIRST METHOD");

    }

    public synchronized static void secondMethod() {
        System.out.println("SECOND METHOD");
        // In actual code I would have try catch for this but here I just didn't
        // include it
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public class MainClass {

    // main method of MainClass
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Thread firstThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    OtherClass.firstMethod();
                }

            }
        };

        Thread secondThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    OtherClass.secondMethod();
                }

            }
        };

        secondThread.start();
        firstThread.start();

    }
}
```

The reason I start the 2nd thread first is because I want the `secondMethod` of `OtherClass` to execute first. I **should** see `"FIRST METHOD"` and `"SECOND METHOD"` in the console output every 5 seconds. The reason being is that since `Thread.sleep` does not relinquish the lock, for 5 seconds the first thread doesn't have access to the first method because the second thread has got a lock on the class while it's in the second method which tells the thread to sleep for 5 seconds. But I get very unexpected results. All I get in the console output is `"SECOND METHOD"` every 5 seconds. The `firstMethod` isn't called.

Comment: You are assigning `firstThread` twice.

Comment: Lol yea sorry about that I'll fix my code.

Comment: I suggest you to use `wait()` and `notify()` to achieve your desired output.

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Ignoring compilation problems in your code.</sub>

That's just coincidence. The thread scheduler simply decides to continue executing the second thread which reacquires the lock too fast.

Run it long enough (or with a shorter sleep time for faster results) and you'll see the other method get invoked.

Comment: But that's bad... It's extremely unpredictable.. How would I fix this?

Comment: @user3843164 That's one among many reasons sleeping a thread is not ideal. _Fixing_ this depends on what you are trying to achieve. You might want to implement a notification mechanism (`wait` and `notify` or `java.util.concurrent` constructs).

Comment: @user3843164 - you might want to look at [guarded blocks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) to implement what *Sotirios* says

Comment: No I know sleeping isn't what I originally wanted I was just testing this code out to see if synchronization works the way I thought. Guess it doesn't...

Comment: @user3843164 The thread scheduler is just not something you can control. You can give it hints, but that's it.

Comment: I tried to use to wait and notify, but I still didn't get what I wanted. The output I am looking for is that "FIRST METHOD" and "SECOND METHOD" are outputted one right after the other. I should get this because both threads should not be able to call both methods at the same time since only one thread can hold the lock for the class. So after one method is done executing, the method that is waiting should be immediately called after since it was waiting for the lock to be released.

Comment: @user3843164 There's no way to do _that_. Each thread gets a window in which it can execute. If it can't get the lock in the window that the thread scheduler gave it, it will block, waiting to try again. Your other thread, apparently, has enough time in its window to complete return from the method invocation, reloop the `while` block and re-invoke the method, re-acquiring the lock. The only to do what you want is to use a proper notification mechanism.

Answer (score 2):

> The reason I start the 2nd thread first is because I want the secondMethod of OtherClass to execute first.

That's not how threads work.  That's not what threads are for.  Threads provide *no* guarantees of what happens before what else except where you provide explicit synchronization between them; And generally speaking, the more synchronization you use, the less you will benefit from having multiple threads.

In your example, you have explicit synchronization that prevents any concurrent executions of firstMethod() and secondMethod(), but you have nothing that guarantees which one will run first, and which one will run second.  Chances are, that main() will terminate before either of them runs.  At that point, it's up to the scheduler to pick which one will run when.  There is no requirement that it start them in the same order that your code called their start() methods.

Your example may be educational, but it also is an example of when *not* to use threads.  Your synchronization is very heavy handed.  Your program basically does two things, firstMethod() and secondMethod(), and the synchronization insures that they can not be overlapped.  In production software, if you have two tasks that must not overlap, then it'll simplify your program's logic if they are always performed by the same thread.

> All I get in the console output is "SECOND METHOD" every 5 seconds. The firstMethod isn't called.

Your question was edited before I got to see it, so I don't know whether you're talking about the original version, or the fixed version.  But in any case:

The synchronization in your program does *not* guarantee that the two threads take turns.  All it does is prevent them both from printing at the same time.

Each of your threads runs a loop that grabs the lock, prints something, releases the lock, and then immediately tries to grab the lock again.  When a running thread releases a lock, and then immediately tries to get it again, the chances are it will succeed.  It doesn't matter that some other thread was waiting for the lock.  The OS doesn't know what your program is trying to accomplish, but it *does* know that it can make more efficient use of the CPU by letting a thread continue to run instead of blocking it and un-blocking some other thread.

You will need to use some additional synchronization to make the threads take turns, but like I said, in a real program, the more synchronization you use, the less benefit there is to using threads.

Comment: Ok good point, but actually since you said all this let me tell you what I really am doing and trying to get out of this. I am making a game in Android. What I need is a drawing thread and a logic thread. Now in game development it's common to use two threads for drawing and game logic, even if putting them in the same thread may simplify the code, it will be slower because the drawing thread is handling all the logic too. What I need is to run my drawing operations, then update right after, then draw, then update, and so forth. I need them to run right after each other.

Comment: So I need to make sure that an update or draw isn't skipped because of some thread scheduler, they HAVE to run right after each other for optimal results.

Comment: @user3843164 If you are trying to achieve this in Android,why don't you go for `Handler`

Comment: @user3843164, I'm not a GUI developer, but in my understanding of how such things work, you usually want the drawing thread to run asynchronously, and at a lower priority.  The logic thread maintains the game state in real-time, and the drawing thread does the best it can to render the current state to the screen.

Comment: Ok but I still can't have drawing and updating overlapping each other, I need to make a full update to all the values and then draw them. If I run both at different speeds, the game will be extremely choppy because updating is happening much faster than the drawing.

Comment: @user3843164, "in game development it's common to use two threads for drawing and game logic"  Yes, but if your two threads strictly take turns, then you are ignoring the reason why games are designed that way.  If the logic and drawing tasks never overlap, then there's no benefit to doing them in separate threads.  You will end up building something that superficially looks like a conventional game, but which does not work like one.  Again, I'm not a GUI/Game designer, so I can't judge what you will or will not learn from that activity.

Comment: The only other way I can think of is to use a blocking queue.. is this what you're saying?

Comment: This way they do overlap but the game doesn't appear to be choppy because the drawing thread is reading from the queue(meaning all of the updates) but the updating still runs at full speed and is blocked if the queue gets like way too huge or something.

Answer (score 0):

Your processor won't execute your Threads at the same time; it'll run your second thread every time bevore your first thread.

The behaviour is clear: Your processor executes your second thread. Then, the processor executes your first thread and sees that it is locked by your second thread. After 5 seconds, your second thread is called again. It makes the output, releases the lock and locks it again. If your first thread is called again, it is locked again.

To fix this, add `Thread.yield()` at the end of your while. This will make the processor call the first thread before continuing to execute your second thread (the first thread won't be the only one that is called, it just removes your second thread 1 time from it's execution). Then your first thread gets the lock, waits 5 seconds, outputs and calls `Thread.yield()`; then your second thread gets the lock again and so on.

Comment: Why would the second thread keep releasing and locking? I mean the exact time that the second thread releases the lock the first thread should be there to get it because it was waiting for the lock to be released..

Comment: @user3843164 Yes, the first thread waits for the second thread to release the lock. But the second thread locks it before the first thread is able to notice that the lock was released for this short time. What you described above is exactly what happens when using `Thread.yield()`

Comment: Note that `Thread#yield()` is just a hint. The thread scheduler can ignore it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yes he can ignore it; there is no safety that it will happen. Is there another way to interrupt the thread from execution by only 1 round in java?

Comment: No, `wait` and `notify` are the proper way to do this (if it has to be done in separate threads).

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is thread starvation.  In your case, one thread is being blocked indefinitely waiting to enter a synchronization block because the other thread is constantly allowed access.

To overcome thread starvation you need to employ some sort of fairness locking.  Locks that are conceived as fair give priority to the threads waiting the longest to acquire said lock.  Such a locking strategy eliminates the possibility of thread starvation and insures all waiting threads will be executed at some time.

Fairness locking in Java can easily be accomplished by using a [ReentrantLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) with a fairness parameter set to true.